# Named query with parameters in HQL - Throwing System.IndexOutOfRangeException in class NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElement.RenderText

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

When upgrading from NHibernate version 3.1.0.4 to 4.0.4.4 an IndexOutOfRangeException is encountered.

An HQL named query containing parameters is causing the IndexOutOfRangeException when entering the RenderText() method of the NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElement clas. HQL query below:

```
<query name="NameQuery">
    <![CDATA[
    select od.id, od.Assigned.Number
    from  od
    where od.Status = :status
        and od.Assigned.Number in (:number)
    ]]>
</query>
```

The NHibernate code keeps an array of parameters. When attempting to reference the first index it is recognized that the array is empty and the IndexOutOfRangeException is thrown. Below is the output of the stack trace:

```
**System.IndexOutOfRangeException**: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElement.RenderText(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Tree\FromElement.cs:line 347
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.Out(IASTNode n) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\SqlGenerator.cs:line 137
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.NestedFromFragment(IASTNode d, IASTNode parent) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\SqlGenerator.cs:line 260
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.tableJoin(IASTNode parent) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\SqlGenerator.cs:line 3492
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.fromTable() in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\SqlGenerator.cs:line 3260
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.from() in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\SqlGenerator.cs:line 3137
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.selectStatement() in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\SqlGenerator.cs:line 376
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.statement() in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\SqlGenerator.cs:line 274
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlGenerator.Generate() in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs:line 609
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs:line 351
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Compile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs:line 70
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.cs:line 39
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.cs:line 24
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan.CreateTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\QueryExpressionPlan.cs:line 32
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan..ctor(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\QueryExpressionPlan.cs:line 13
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters) in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\QueryPlanCache.cs:line 67
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.CheckNamedQueries() in c:\Users\x\Downloads\nhibernate-core-4.0.x\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionFactoryImpl.cs:line 1157
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners) in c:\Users\x\Downloads
```

I have not been successful in identifying what is causing this parameter Array to be empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know the trouble occurs on first index access, and that the array is empty at the point it tries to use it? `Index out of range` does not tell which index it has attempt to access. May you add the call you use to set parameters on your query then execute it?